# Connection Retry via OLE DB VS ADO.NET in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssis, ado.net, oledb

**Problem**: We want to achieve Connection resiliency in SSIS Packages(OLE DB vs ADO.NET Connection manager)

**Environment Details**:

Database: SQL Server 2016

SSIS Connection manager: OLEDB

OLEDB Provider : Microsoft OLE DB Driver 19.3.2 for SQL Server

**Observation**:

1. OLE DB

· We upgraded the OLEDB provider in the client and server to the above version.

· And Added Connect Retry Count and Connect Retry Interval in below connection string.

*“Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=pqr; IntegratedSecurity=SSPI;Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19.1;Auto Translate=False;Connect Retry Count = 6;Connect Retry Interval = 60;Connect Timeout= 600;TrustServerCertificate=True; Use Encryption for Data=False;”*

· However, the connection retry did not work.

2. ADO.NET

· We changed the connection manager to ADO.NET(.Net Providers\SqlClient Data Provider)

· Used the connection String as below and the connection retry worked.

*“Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=pqr; Integrated Security=SSPI;ConnectRetryCount = 6;ConnectRetryInterval = 60;Connect Timeout = 600;"*

**Inputs needed:**:

· Is connection retry possible through OLE DB connection manager? Have we missed something in our test?

· We are considering to migrate from OLE DB to ADO.NET connection manager in all our packages. What could be the potential risk of doing this? (This is not a preferred option for us since dataflow task does not work with ADO.NET Connection manager also this would be a huge effort to update all task in our SSIS package portfolio.)

Comment: Why do you need to retry in the first place? And why would retrying improve the connection if the server is completely offline?